# Rails Validate Unless Association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Just wondering what the best call it use when validating unless an object has an association. For example: I want to validate a user's email and password unless it has one authentication (OAuth). I tried using:

```
# user.rb
has_many :authentications
validates_presence_of :email, :unless => "authentications.exists?"
validates_presence_of :password, :unless => "authentications.exists?"
```

Which worked fine for 'updates' but not 'creates'.

Comment: The default for `validates_presence_of` is that it occurs `:on => :save`, so I'm not sure why you're seeing this problem... have you changed your `User.create` method??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `validates_presence_of :email, :unless => "authentications.present?"`